# How to carry tensor(s) through iterations of external tf.while_loop (dynamic_rnn)?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm implementing specific RNN cell wrapper ([Adaptive Computation Time](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.08983) by Alex Graves). As a part of my implementation, I need to provide a user with several tensors summarizing some computation happening at each time step (e.g. "ponder cost" used in loss function). Naturally, these tensors need to be created and returned during building of the computation graph.

This is not a problem if `static_rnn` is used for RNN creation, as my wrapper's `call` method is called as many times as there are time steps, so that I can compile all necessary information from each time step into a single tensor. If, however, RNN is created by `dynamic_rnn`, which uses `tf.while_loop` under the hood, the `call` method is called only once for initialization, so I'm not able to capture individual time step results.

Therefore, my question: are there ways to carry tensor(s) through all iterations of an external `tf.while_loop`, from which your method is called, and summarize them (e.g. using `tf.stack` or `tf.reduce_sum`) during graph building time? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I may be missing something in your question, but `dynamic_rnn` will return `(output,state)` where `output` is a tensor with the information for all time steps. Is that what you want?

Comment: This is of course true. The issue, however, is that I need something else than just `output` returned by `dynamic_rnn`. In ACT (referenced paper) each conventional RNN time step may be repeated more than once. So, for example, I need to carry through, sum and return to a user the total number of inner repetitions of each time step. This information is available only within the `call` method of my wrapper and I need somehow to pull it out from `dynamic_rnn`'s internal `tf.while_loop`.